# Customizing JQuery Slider sensitivity

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

In my ASP.Net MVC project, I have used JQuery slider to allow user selecting a big range of values. The range is from 0 to 100000. Unfortunately, I cannot provide good amount of space for the slider looking at limitations of my app size and the UI requirements altogether. Hence the slider is given a width of approx 1 - 2 inches only.

The problem is that, when user moves this slider on screen, the values in aligned textbox jumps very fast (in thousands). And user is not able to select small values say 400 or 500 etc. This is obvious because of the small space and high range combination. I agree.

However, client is not ready to accept this and somehow wants me to reduce the sensitivity of the slider such that it will show values in 100s while sliding.

Is there any way to achieve this using exposed events and properties of Jquery slider?

I am using JQuery-1.6.2.js for this purpose.

Comment: Do you have any source codes you can post? Can you create a fiddle? Can you post anything you've tried already? we need a bit of help to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the slider with step size 100. Then the slider can be moved with less sensitivity.

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({ step: 100 });
```